# If a standard C++ library function returns an int for a char value, does it need to be casted?

Tags: c++, char, int, ifstream, std

For example, the ifstream function
ifstream infile;
infile.peek() //returns an integer

Do I need to cast this int return value as a char or can I compare it directly to another char?
If the latter is the case, does this mean char to char comparison just checks to see if integer ascii values are the same?

Thanks.

Comment: No, but in case you are trying to compare it against `EOF` (I have a feeling...), store it in an `int`, not a `char`. Or just use the return value directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing it with a char literal e.g `'c'` should work due to **Integral Promotion**